# Expresiones regulares en C#

Tags: c#

Estioy desarrollando un evaluador de expresiones, y tengo el siguiente codigo para comprobar que no se de la siguiente combinacion de caracteres

por ejemplo:

*-- una multiplicacion seguida por dos signos de resta

*/  una multiplicacion seguida por una division

*+  una multiplicacion seguida por una suma

este es el codigo que funciona correctamente

```
private static Boolean EvaluaExprMat(String expr)
  {
    for(int pos = 0; pos < expr.Length - 1; pos++)
    {
      char car1 = expr[pos];  
      char car2 = expr[pos + 1]; 

      if (car1 == '+' || car1 == '-' || car1 == '*' || car1 == '/' || car1 == '^')
        if (car2 == '+' || car2 == '*' || car2 == '/' || car2 == '^')
          return true;
    }

    for (int pos = 0; pos < expr.Length - 2; pos++)
    {
      char car1 = expr[pos];  
      char car2 = expr[pos + 1];
      char car3 = expr[pos + 2];


      if (car1 == '+' || car1 == '-' || car1 == '*' || car1 == '/' || car1 == '^')
        if (car2 == '+' || car2 == '-' || car2 == '*' || car2 == '/' || car2 == '^')
          if (car3 == '+' || car3 == '-' || car3 == '*' || car3 == '/' || car3 == '^')
            return true;
    }
```

como podria ejecutar estas evaluaciones usando expresiones regulares? alguien me puede ayudar un poco con este tema, quiero reducir el codigo usando ese tipo de herramienta.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Gloria te adjunto la solucion que pides:

```
        private static Boolean EvaluaExprMat(String expr)
    {
        String filtro = @"(\*\-\-)|(\*\/)|(\*\+) ";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(filtro, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (rgx.IsMatch(expr))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
```

La expresion regular evalua tus 3 requerimientos y devuelve true si alguno se cumple.
Cada requerimiento viene delimitado por los ( ) y cada signo viene precedido por un "\" para que lo utilice como literal ya que por ejemplo el signo "*" tiene su propio significado dentro del mundo de las expresiones regulares

En esta pagina https://regexr.com puedes tanto probar online las expresiones regulares que hagas como de aprender a hacerlas, aunque la explicacion venga en ingles

Comment: Lindo, te pasaste, me funciono muy bien tu solucion ;), te puedo molestar con una cosita mas.. es super simple.. resulta que la expresion matematica que debo evaluar, debe aceptar solo numeros y los simbolos + - *  y / (operaciones matematicas jiji) y estoyusando esta expresion para evaluarla [0-9]|[\*\/\+\-\(\)]  la cual funciona bien, excepto cuando por ejemplo quiero evaluar (a  en ese caso, me dice que esta correcta, aunque tenga el caracter a, sin embargoo cuando solo le paso la a solita, ahi la expresion funciona correctamente.. tu sabes porque pasa esto?

Comment: Hola Gloria no entiendo del todo tu pregunta. ¿Dices que usando "  [0-9]|[*\/\+\-()] " e introduciendo una "a" la funcion te devuelve true? .¿Puedes comentar cual es el resultado que esperas conseguir con la expresion que estas usando?

Comment: ah si, perdona, cometi un error cuando te dije devuelve true, y es porque estoy negando la consulta. mira aca te paso el codigo que estoy usando.

Comment: string ValidPattern;
            ValidPattern = @"[0-9]|[\*\/\+\-\(\)]";
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(Expresion, ValidPattern))
            {
                return false;
            }

Comment: cuando por ejemplo la expresion es (5+8) funciona bien,  tambien cuando por ejemplo la expresion es una a, pero cuando la expresion es por ejemplo (a + 8) tambien me devuelve un true esta funcion.

Comment: Hola Gloria , veo que en tu expresion regular no contemplas que hayan letras, si introduces "(5+8)" habra coincidencia, pero si introduces "a" o "(a + 8)" no habra coincidencia por que no lo has indicado.Si quieres  contemplar letras tambien prueba @"([A-Za-z]|[0-9])|[*\/\+\-()]"

Comment: es que precisamente no quiero que acepte letras de ningun tipo, por eso te decia que cuando la expresion es por ejemplo 5+a para mi eso no deberia ser valido, sin embargo a pesar que el pattern indica que no acepta letras, el resultado de esa evaluacion si las acepta

Comment: Victor Manuel, ya resolvi lo que me estaba fallando, use otra evaluacion donde solo veo si hay letras desde la a a la z (mayusculas y minusculas) con eso ya evito que el programa siga adelante si la epresion viene con letras. Agradezco mucho tu ayuda. que tengas un lindo fin de semana :)

Comment: De nada, acabo de ver y simplemente tu anterior expresion "[0-9] |[*\/\+\-()]" comprueba si es un numero o si es un signo, por lo que si pones una "a" no cumple ninguna pero si pones una a+5 cumple el signo y el numero. Un placer